# How to update recyclerview the simplest way using notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to update my recyclerview using notifyDataSetChanged() but it doesn't work. I am setting the adapter to the recyclerview like this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
lstSong.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
lstSong.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
lstSong.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(0), true));

arrSong = new ArrayList<Song>();
arrSong = kFunc.getAllSong();
songAdapter = new SongAdapter(ctx, arrSong);
lstSong.setAdapter(songAdapter);
```

This lines of code displays the data. But when i add a new data and refresh the recyclerview with `songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` the data won't show up. I know i can display it by using `setAdapter()` but i want to do it properly.

I add the data before I make the refresh. This is the code:

```
kFunc = new Function(ctx);
Song song = new Song();
song.setTitle(title);
song.setArtist(artist);
song.setYear_released(yearReleased);
song.setAlbum(album);
song.setGenre(genre);
song.setDuration(duration);
song.setCode(code);
song.setLyrics(lyrics);

kFunc.addSong(song);
dialog.dismiss();

arrSong = kFunc.getAllSong();
songAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: can share you code where you are adding new item in recyclerview

Comment: Can I see your code of SongAdapter to check how to add new item?

Comment: Instead of arrSong = kFunc.getAllSong(); this use arrSong.addAll(kFunc.getAllSong());

Comment: wow, @JRamesh it worked. it's the first time i used that code. before i remembered that i just used notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Create a method inside adapter like

```
public updateItems(ArrayList<Song> songs){
    arrSong=songs;
}
```

And while getting new values in your class call the method using adapdter object

```
lstSong.updateItems(arrSong);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i am doing something similar to that in my adapter's constructor

Comment: Yes constructor is only for the first time.When data changes you have to update the reference again through the method.Add this method inside your   adatper and call it from class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you added new item to `RecyclerView.Adapter`. This is a sample code to add and set a item. More detail [Sample RecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/kimkevin/androidpack/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/kimkevin/androidpack/adapter/RecyclerViewAdapter.java)

```
  @Override
  public void addItem(M item) {
    items.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void addItem(int position, M item) {
    items.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
  }

  @Override
  public void addAllItems(List<M> items) {
    this.items.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public void setItems(List<M> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try by updating the list of the songs before you notify the adapter. 
for example

`arraySongs = <retrive updated data of the song>;
adapter.notifyDataStateChanged()`

if you are in ListView which you are not but for you information only.
`adapter.lstSong =<updated songs List>;
adapter.notifyDataStteChanged();`

try this this worked for me.
happy coding. :)

Comment: @RickyManalo you should try to update the list which is inside of the adapter.

Comment: like create a method inside the adapter which update the list. and then try to notify the adapter

Comment: why do i need to create a method for updating the list? doesn't the adapter supposed to just show the data

Comment: maybe the list is private so that you can't access the list outside of the class(adapter) but you can also do that by simply `adapter.lstSongs = <updated song List>`